# Convert string to valid XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following string:

```
<String Name=XPTO><nullCheck><fixedLength length=2 justify=left>
```

It's almost a valid XML except for values ​​that don't have `""`

I would like to know how I can convert to this:

```
<String Name="XPTO"><nullCheck><fixedLength length="2" justify="left">
```

Comment: Do you have access to the source of the XML? It's going to be much better/less of a headache to clean them up at the source, if possible.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the file that I have it's not a .XML it's a .cgm

Comment: Well, there are a number of ways to do that; search for "=" and ">" and put quotes after and before respectively. It would be great if you could show what you've tried so far so we can use that as a basis, rather than listing all of the ways of doing it...